# How to solve this recurrence relation $ f(n) = \frac{10+7f(n-1)}{2+f(n-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

I had a problem in which I ended up getting the following recurrence relation:

$$\begin{align}
&f(1) = 7\\
&f(n) = \dfrac{10+7f(n-1)}{2+f(n-1)}
\end{align}$$

I haven't solved much recurrence relations, and I am unaware of any general procedure. The only thing I was able to do till now was to get this relation. I have tried putting $n$ as $n+1$, but it soon gets unsolvable.

In a more crude form, $$f(n) = 5+ \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{f(n-1)}+\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Very nice problem, but quite a hard one.

Comment: @Max Payne is this an actual precalculus question given to you?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla No it was a physics question about equivalent resistance of an infinite ladder. The only variation was that the ladder had finite $n$ steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutions for
$$x=\frac{10+7x}{2+x}$$
are $x=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{65}}{2}$.

Then,
$$f(n)-\frac{5\pm\sqrt{65}}{2}=\frac{10+7f(n-1)}{2+f(n-1)}-\frac{5\pm\sqrt{65}}{2}=\frac{10\mp 2\sqrt{65}+(9\mp\sqrt{65})f(n-1)}{2(2+f(n-1))}$$
from which we have
$$\begin{align}\frac{f(n)-(5+\sqrt{65})/2}{f(n)-(5-\sqrt{65})/2}&=\frac{{10- 2\sqrt{65}+(9-\sqrt{65})f(n-1)}}{{10+ 2\sqrt{65}+(9+\sqrt{65})f(n-1)}}\\&=\frac{9-\sqrt{65}}{9+\sqrt{65}}\cdot \frac{f(n-1)-(5+\sqrt{65})/2}{f(n-1)-(5-\sqrt{65})/2}\end{align}$$
which can be written as
$$g(n)=\alpha g(n-1)$$
This is a geometric progression
where $$g(n)=\frac{f(n)-(5+\sqrt{65})/2}{f(n)-(5-\sqrt{65})/2},\quad \alpha=\frac{9-\sqrt{65}}{9+\sqrt{65}}$$
Having $g(n)=\alpha^n$, we have
$$\begin{align}f(n)&=\frac{(5+\sqrt{65})/2-\alpha^n\cdot(5-\sqrt{65})/2}{1-\alpha^n}\\&=\color{red}{\frac{(5+\sqrt{65})(9+\sqrt{65})^n-(5-\sqrt{65})(9-\sqrt{65})^n}{2((9+\sqrt{65})^n-(9-\sqrt{65})^n)}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

Let we state it in a slightly different way. Let $(a_1,b_1)=(7,1)$ and:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}7 & 10 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_{n} \\ b_{n}\end{pmatrix} = M \begin{pmatrix} a_{n} \\ b_{n}\end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues of $M$ are $\frac{9\pm\sqrt{65}}{2}$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the characteristic polynomial of the sequence
$$ \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}\right\}_{n\geq 1} $$
is the same as the characteristic polynomial of $M$. Component-wise, we have:
$$ a_n = A_+ \left(\frac{9+\sqrt{65}}{2}\right)^n + A_- \left(\frac{9-\sqrt{65}}{2}\right)^n, $$
$$ b_n = B_+ \left(\frac{9+\sqrt{65}}{2}\right)^n + B_- \left(\frac{9-\sqrt{65}}{2}\right)^n, $$
where the constants $A_{\pm},B_{\pm}$ can be found by computing the first values of $(a_i,b_i)$, then solving a linear system. In our case $(a_1,b_1)=(7,1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)=(59,9)$ give:

> $$ \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{(5+\sqrt{65})(9+\sqrt{65})^n-(5-\sqrt{65})(9-\sqrt{65})^n}{2((9+\sqrt{65})^n-(9-\sqrt{65})^n)}$$

but the LHS is exactly $f(n)$. That also gives us:

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} f(n) = \color{red}{\frac{5+\sqrt{65}}{2}}.$$

Comment: I presently do not understand your procedure, but it certainly is a good answer!

The **source** of the problem was infinite ladder resistor and a part of question was to calculate the limit as n tends to infinity, and it didn't require solving the relation. The limit did actually came out to be the same as you got, by using the same trick as the accepted answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/equivalent-resistance-in-ladder-circuit