# How do i show bellow that :$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}>1$ without looking to $ u_{n+1}-u_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ratio

let $(u_n)$ be a sequence defined as :

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{n+1}=3-\frac{10}{u_n+4} ,& 0<u_n<1\\
u_0=\frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}
$$
The above sequence is increasing by using the difference :$ u_{n+1}-u_n$ , really i have tried to look if the ratio $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ greater than $1$, but i don't succeed ,**Then is it possible to show that is increasing sequence using the ratio $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ without using the difference:$ u_{n+1}-u_n$** ?

Comment: I generally don't like stealing (even incomplete) answers, so, giving this as a comment. Look at the $f(x)=3-\frac{10}{x+4}$, deduce it is increasing, show $f(u_0)>u_0$ and then use induction to show $u_{n}>u_{n-1} \Rightarrow f(u_{n})>f(u_{n-1})$ which is $u_{n+1}>u_{n}$ ... for an example [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551561/i-want-to-know-the-limits-and-convergence-divergence-of-a-n1-fraca-n/2552108#2552108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inequality given:
$$0<u_{n}<1$$
$$4< u_n + 4< 5$$
$$\frac{1}{5}< \frac{1}{u_{n} + 4}$$
$$\therefore 1< \frac{5}{u_{n} + 4}$$
Now using the given formula divide by $u_{n}$ and simplify:
$$u_{n+1} = 3 - \frac{10}{u_n +4}$$
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{3u_n + 2}{u_n(u_n + 4)}$$
Working with inequalities again:
$$0<u_{n}<1$$
$$2u_{n}<2$$
$$5u_n< 3u_n +2$$
$$\frac{5u_n}{u_n(u_n + 4)} < \frac{3u_n + 2}{u_n(u_n + 4)}$$
$$\frac{5}{u_n + 4} < \frac{3u_n + 2}{u_n(u_n + 4)}$$
$$1< \frac{3u_n + 2}{u_n(u_n + 4)} \:\:\: \because 1< \frac{5}{u_{n} + 4}$$
$$\therefore 1< \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$$
This is a basic manipulation. This can be proved with other more efficient methods.